# Rails strong params not working with autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Groups controller

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    autocomplete :group, :name, :full => true

    def index
     @group = Group.new
    end

    def create

    end

    private

    def group_params
      params.require(:group).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

When I am submitting params with following form :

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_group_name_groups_path, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true, :"data-autocomplete-label" => "Sorry, nothing found."
 %>
 <%= f.submit "Find" %>
<% end%>
```

I am getting following params in server :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"r/V8df6WtVVwh2i8QeJwxG0rxoF90cN7kpdsLPzoZzk72v3C+JOCNx5FuOD3RYTRS7jIZlWcbAdQ05iUEmw==", "group"=>{"name"=>["nyc"]}, "commit"=>"Find", "controller"=>"groups", "action"=>"create"}
```

But when I am trying to call **group_params** I am getting empty {}

Please tell me what is problem with the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `params.require(:group).permit(:name => [])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look into the `params` hash, the ***values*** for `name` coming in an ***array***, so the below should work

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:name => [])
end
```